# How to should I throw this PHP exception such that it will return an array?

Tags: php, symfony

Here is the situation:

```
$errors = $this->validator->validate($request);

if (\count($errors) > 0) {
    $errorBag = ErrorMessageHelper::generateErrorMessage($errors);

    throw new CustomException(json_encode($errorBag), Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

Over here, `$errorBag` returns an array.

When I throw this exception: my response looks something like this:

```
"error":{"code":500,"message":"{\"postalCode\":\"This value should have exactly 7 characters.\"}"}
```

Notice the message above which is json encoded.

Does anyone have any idea how to throw it properly ( message should be a proper json object )

What I tried to override CustomException but it doesnt work and it returns an empty response.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Json_decode?   http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: `json_encode()` creates a String of JSON. JSON is not readily available to use with PHP. You use it for AJAXing back to JavaScript.

Comment: @BrianPatterson Nope. It would convert it to an array and the exception will throw an error

Comment: @PHPglue what if I want to send it as a neat JSON string ?

Comment: Looks good to me already.

Comment: What is json_last_error returning?

Comment: Try json_decode($errorBag[0])

Comment: json_last_error returns the same error message. Its like a stack of previous error messages that Ive tried

Comment: Which one?     JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error has occurred',
        JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded',
        JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH => 'Invalid or malformed JSON',
        JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
        JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
        JSON_ERROR_UTF8 => '

Comment: Did you end up getting this figured out?

Comment: I think that JSON is well-formed and can be used further.

Answer (score 0):

Can you integrate this class easily? 
`

```
class JsonHandler {

protected static $_messages = array(
    JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error has occurred',
    JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded',
    JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH => 'Invalid or malformed JSON',
    JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
    JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
    JSON_ERROR_UTF8 => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'
);

public static function encode($value, $options = 0) {
    $result = json_encode($value, $options);

    if($result)  {
        return $result;
    }

    throw new RuntimeException(static::$_messages[json_last_error()]);
}

public static function decode($json, $assoc = false) {
    $result = json_decode($json, $assoc);

    if($result) {
        return $result;
    }

    throw new RuntimeException(static::$_messages[json_last_error()]);
}

}
`
```

Comment: It is obvious. I get this error :

"error":{"code":0,"message":"Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"}

Since, $errorBag is an array

Comment: Thats smart. What if we need all the information from array ?